# When we should use scala.util.DynamicVariable?

Tags: scala, thread-local

When I read the source of scalatra, I found there are some code like:

```
protected val _response   = new DynamicVariable[HttpServletResponse](null)
protected val _request    = new DynamicVariable[HttpServletRequest](null)
```

There is an interesting class named `DynamicVariable`. I've looked at the doc of this class, but I don't know when and why we should use it? It has a `withValue()` which is usually be used.

If we don't use it, then what code we should use instead, to solve the problem it solved?

(I'm new to scala, if you can provide some code, that will be great)

Comment: http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/scala-Thread-Local-context-made-easy-with-Scala-td1997909.html

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`DynamicVariable` is an implementation of the loan and dynamic scope patterns. Use-case of `DynamicVariable` is pretty much similar to `ThreadLocal` in Java (as a matter of fact, `DynamicVariable` uses `InheritableThreadLocal` behind the scenes) - it's used, when you need to do a computation within an enclosed scope, where every thread has it's own copy of the variable's value:

```
dynamicVariable.withValue(value){ valueInContext =>
  // value used in the context
}
```

Given that `DynamicVariable` uses an inheritable `ThreadLocal`, value of the variable is passed to the threads spawned in the context:

```
dynamicVariable.withValue(value){ valueInContext =>
  spawn{
    // value is passed to the spawned thread
  }
}
```

`DynamicVariable` (and `ThreadLocal`) is used in Scalatra for the same reason it's used in many other frameworks (Lift, Spring, Struts, etc.) - it's a non-intrusive way to store and pass around context(thread)-specific information.

Making `HttpServletResponse` and `HttpServletRequest` dynamic variables (and, thus, binding to a specific thread that processes request) is just the easiest way to obtain them anywhere in the code (not passing through method arguments or anyhow else explicitly).

Answer (score 25):

This is well answered by Vasil, but I'll add an additional simple example that might further help understanding.

Suppose we must use some code that uses println() to write all over stdout.  We want this output to go to a log file, but we don't have access to the source.

- `println()` uses `Console.println()`
- `Console.println()` (fortunately) is [based on](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/src/library/scala/Console.scala#L76) a `DynamicVariable[PrintStream]` that defaults to `java.lang.System.out`
- `Console` defines [`withOut`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/src/library/scala/Console.scala#L107) that just forwards to the dynamic variable's `withValue`

We can use this to simply fix our issue:

```
def noisy() { println("robot human robot human") }
noisy() // prints to stdout
val ps = new java.io.PrintStream("/tmp/mylog")
scala.Console.withOut(ps) { noisy() } // output now goes to /tmp/mylog file
```

Answer (score 18):

This is a minimal snippet:

```
val dyn = new DynamicVariable[String]("withoutValue")
def print=println(dyn.value)
print
dyn.withValue("withValue") {
  print
}
print
```

The output will be:

```
withoutValue
withValue
withoutValue
```