# Does ScalaMock support mocking of (companion) objects and constructors?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mocking, scalamock

There are somewhat contradictory statements about the abilities of ScalaMock to mock (companion) objects and constructors. The page [ScalaMock step-by-step](http://paulbutcher.com/2011/11/06/scalamock-step-by-step/) states

it can also mock:

- Classes
  *Singleton and companion objects (static methods)
- Object creation (constructor invocation)
- Classes with private constructors
- Final classes and classes with final methods
- Operators (methods with symbolic names)
- Overloaded methods

On the other hand the [roadmap](http://scalamock.org/roadmap/) tells me:

First Quarter 2016 - ScalaMock 4
As soon as scala.meta is available, we plan to start working on ScalaMock 4. If scala.meta delivers on its promise, ScalaMock 4 should be able to mock any trait, no matter how complex its type.

In addition, we expect that it will also support:

- improved syntax: mockObject.expects.method(arguments) instead of: (mockObject.method _) expects (arguments)
- mocking object creation (constructors)
- mocking singleton and companion objects (static methods)
- mocking final classes and classes with final methods or private constructors

**So,  what is correct? Is the current version (ScalaMock 3.2) able to mock objects and constructors, or not?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some more research it looks like mocking objects and constructors was once supported, but isn't in the current version. [Mocking of objects should be reintroduced with ScalaMock 4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25309601/238134).