# Scala mock framework that can mock singleton objects

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mocking

can some one recommend me to scala mocking framework that can mock singleton objects and also does not need to declare any annotations as such. Basically i need a mock frame work that would not make me force to change the existing code base.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mock a Scala singleton object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25293758/how-to-mock-a-scala-singleton-object)

Comment: @danielnixon that post says scalamock framework can not mock singleton/companion objects so suggest to change the design of the system. I can not change the design. The code that i want to mock is already in production.So i am looking for a framework that can mock singleton/companion objects

Comment: There is no such framework/library for Scala, AFAIK. There are two such libraries for the Java language (JMockit and PowerMock), but they probably don't work well for Scala code. I would suggest to open a feature/enhancement request in the ScalaMock project.

Comment: Just found an issue to add singleton mocking support to ScalaMock [already exists](https://github.com/paulbutcher/ScalaMock/issues/41).